# How to visualize AWS Elastic Beanstalk application logs

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

We are using AWS Elastic Beanstalk for deploying application. Currently we have two Elastic Beanstalk applications and two worker processes (that pick message from AWS SQS Queue and process it).

What can be the best tools to view the combine logs from the Elastic Beanstalk application and worker and a few more on-premise applications in future?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the suggestion and configured Cloud watch logs, Elastic Search, and Kibana; but i am not getting all logs and all insights.  I can see httpd access & error logs, ebs access & error logs.  It also seems lot of AWS services and configuration. Since I am very new to AWS; therefore, so I am facing trouble in setting things up

Alternatively as suggested by my boss, I tried "New relic" - It was very simple to configure and I can see lot of insights of my EBS application in "New Relic" console.  I can also configure my Browser, iOS app, Android app, AWS infrastructure (AWS Services) in one New Relic console. Some details are missing in New Relic console such error stack trace, request params in POST request, and so on; But I also don't want to share such details with New Relic, so, that is ok.

I will use "New Relic" and Cloudwatch logs (for real time investigation into failing HTTP REST services) right now; but I will explore more options inside AWS: Elastic Search and Kibana

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Throw the logs in [AWS ElasticSearch](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/) and the use [Kibana](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/kibana/), which comes with ElasticSearch, to visualize them.